# jasper reportts как подкрасить строку в зависимости от поля?

Tags: java, jasperreports

```
  <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement style="Detail" backcolor="#E6F4FC"  stretchType="ElementGroupBottom" x="0" y="0" width="70" height="22" uuid="b45e49d2-9373-45d9-ac9c-6d9d806e1831"/>
            <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="styled">
                <font size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{channel}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

допустим это одно из полей, у него  backcolor="#E6F4FC"   как можно менять цвет в зависимости от поля `<![CDATA[$F{channel}]]>` ?? т.е. если оно равно 1 то подкрасить данным цветом,  если не равно 1 то ничеое ставить,  это файл jrxml что то не смог нагуглить синтаксиса

Answer (score 0):

Цвет фона элементов, определяемый значением выражения в JR можно определять с помощью свойства:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor
```

не забывая при этом установить элементам

```
mode="Opaque"
```

в вашем примере блок reportElement нужно изменить следующим образом:

```
<reportElement style="Detail" stretchType="ElementGroupBottom" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="70" height="22" backcolor="#E6F4FC" uuid="b45e49d2-9373-45d9-ac9c-6d9d806e1831">
    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor"><![CDATA[$F{channel} == 1 ? "#E6F4FC" : "#FFFFFF"]]></propertyExpression>
</reportElement>
```

Кроме того, существуют и другие пути для управления цветом по условию, такие как, например, условные стили или условная видимость.